# Java Local variable inaccessible to nested statements

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am working on a project and ran into a problem. I have the following code:

```
private void evaluateCurrentOperation() {

    double token;
    Object currentOperator = thisExprStack.pop();
    double currentOperand;
    double result = 0.0;

    while (!thisOpStack.isEmpty()) {
        currentOperand = thisOpStack.pop();

        if (currentOperator.equals('+')) {
            result += currentOperand;
        }
        if (currentOperator.equals('-')) {
            result -= currentOperand;
        }
        if (currentOperator.equals('/')) {
            result /= currentOperand;
        }
        if (currentOperator.equals('*')) {
            result *= currentOperand;
        }

    }
    thisExprStack.push(result);

}
```

I am using Eclipse and when I tried to use the local variable "result" inside the if blocks I had a warning saying that result was not being used. I am confused because I clearly used this variable but it acts like it doesn't exist. I am new to Java so I do not know how to debug my code.

When I push "result" onto "thisExprStack", it pushes 0.0. The value it was initialized to. How do I get it to push the "result" inside the if blocks?

Comment: The variable is clearly "accessible" since you're able to assign to it.  Is the problem that you're not reading the variable anywhere, so they compiler is warning you that although you're writing to it you're not subsequently "using" it anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

Ignore the previous answer. Are the relevant thisExprStack and thisOpStack populated?

Comment: Even after changing it to this, the result is still not affected.

Comment: Of course its not, this answer is incorrect, casting does not change anything apart from a few instructions and more restricted typing.

Comment: thisExprStack is populated and I just realized that I am having trouble with the next part. I am supposed to pop operands from thisExprStack onto thisOpStack until I find an operator. I am not sure how to accomplish this with a while loop.